# Include GROUP BY id In my Mysql Statement

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I have implemented a solution to filter my table but it has also made me lost one of the main functionalities I wanted. GROUP BY ID DESC so the latest are posted at the top.

The first time you view the table without any filters I would like it to also be GROUP BY ID DESC but the way the filters are setup I cannot do it. Any way to work around it? My code is below

```
<?php 
// Check connection
require '../inc/connection.php';
//Select All from Game
$result_else = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE listDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE ";

//Search Function
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['search_box']);   
$result_else .= "AND Region LIKE'%{$search_term}%'";
$result_else .= "OR gameType LIKE'%{$search_term}%' GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
}

?>
```

If I wanted the original view of the table without any filters to have the GROUP BY ID DESC LIMIT 25 how would this be done?

Thanks for any help

Comment: group by is needed when you use any aggregation method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, can be done

```
$result_else = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE listDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE ";

//Search Function
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['search_box']);   
    $result_else .= "AND Region LIKE'%{$search_term}%'";
    $result_else .= "OR gameType LIKE'%{$search_term}%' ";
}
// $result_else .= "GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
$result_else .= "ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
```

But not sure you are asking for `GROUP BY`  or `ORDER BY`

[`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) groups the content.

[`ORDER BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) orders the content in `asc` or `desc` order

Comment: Much appreciated, at first it didn't work but I forgot to change the rest of my search functions to AND instead of where. does this work because it always adds the $result_else .= "Order by... After the first result else has ran as well the if isset ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you:

```
<?php
// Check connection
require '../inc/connection.php';
//Select All from Game
$result_else = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE listDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE ";

//Search Function
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['search_box']);
    $result_else .= " AND Region LIKE'%{$search_term}%'";
    $result_else .= " OR gameType LIKE'%{$search_term}%' GROUP BY id DESC";
}
$result_else .= " ORDER BY id LIMIT 25";

?>
```